# Rails 5 Devise login via AJAX using Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

Currently, I am trying to get a regular Devise sign_in form working using AJAX using bootstrap modals. The sign_in part works fine on a server side - user get signed in, but the problem is I can't get front end request handling in place as JS is not firing.

> sessions_controller.rb #create

```
  def create
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      sign_in :user, resource
      return render :json => {:success => true}
    end

    invalid_login_attempt
  end
```

This part works fine - user gets signed in with 200 "success" response in the request.

> Sign in form (default one for devise)

```
<%= form_for(resource, url: session_path(:user), remote: true) do |f|  %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email', class: "form-control center-block" %>

  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control center-block' %>

  <%= f.submit 'log in', class: 'center-block btn btn-sp btn-lg'%>
<% end %>
```

Form is pre-rendered with hidden Bootstrap modal which of course get visible on click.

> And the JS which is not firing

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#new_user', function(){
  console.log("in");
});
```

I tried `ajaxSuccess`, older `.bind` syntax, putting JS at app level and rendered right after the form, but can't seem to get that JS to fire and I am running out of ideas, so any help is appreciated. Running on Rails 5, Ruby 2.3.1, jquery-rails 4.1.1.

Comment: Hi, I got exactly same issue with rails 5 and my controller is similar to yours. Have you managed what was the problem? Most tutroials on ajax auth based on rails 4 which I assume not working in rails 5. for example failed status: Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as JS ---- Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms) but ajax is not firing at all for both success and failiture